# Folder keeps changing to read-only

Tags: windows

I'm trying to change a folder to read and write but everytime i check it again its read only

the folder is the oracle db home. When i untick read-only it it applies it but when i press ok check it again it's read-only

anyone know a solution?

i've got windows xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read-only attribute on folders doesn't actually mean the folder is read-only.

It doesn't mean anything much at all to the filesystem but it is used by the Windows shell, and maybe other applications, as a tag. For example, the Windows shell will only look for a Desktop.ini file if a folder has the read-only attribute set. (Thus the attribute allows it to avoid the lookup if it is missing, since the lookup can be quite slow on network drives.)

Unless you have a reason to care about the attribute the solution is to ignore it and let whatever is setting it have its way. It's probably setting it for a reason.

On the other hand, the read-only attribute on *files* is significant.

Comment: "The read-only attribute on folders doesn't actually mean the folder is read-only." - No. Of course not. Why would it? Just windows being helpful and misdirecting everyone for their own good. Hush now child. /Rage

Comment: @IainHolder what do you expect? to have a read-only attribute which is the read only attribute? of course it's not! it's not the real one! it's a fake read only attribute made just for fun!