# How Do I Untick Read Only From Folders in Windows 10 if it Denies Permission?

Tags: permissions, windows-10, readonly

I installed a program to my external HDD, and it wanted to create a file path named Program Files (x86) on my external drive, but I switched it to the path I always use; Program Files\Programs (on the external drive). The folders it made remained, so while it was downloading, I kept deleting the folder, and it kept being remade.

It got annoying, so I set the Program Files folder to Read Only so it would stop making the folder(s) hoping it would stop once it was denied. I changed it back just before my program installed its downloaded files, only to see Windows tell me the drive was 11 TB in size (it's not), and then it spent 6 hours changing every folder and file to Untick Read Only. Or so I thought.

That whole time it was doing nothing at all. All folders were Read Only. Not the files inside, mostly the folders, and I kept getting errors each time I tried to untick Read Only and Apply it.

```
"An error occurred while applying information to: E:\FileName Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied."
```

This error was shown for a long list of files, and then it just wouldn't apply the change.

I Keep looking at threads but anytime it seems like someone is about to reach a solution, the thread stops getting replies.

Trying to troubleshoot and change permissions did not work any better on the computer's Administrator profile than it did on my normal User profile. As it is now, I am not allowed to make a new folder in, or delete an existing folder from within this initial folder, but I can do anything from outside of the folder, on the same drive.

Here is what I have read/tried so far:

[Folder keeps changing to read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489131/folder-keeps-changing-to-read-only)

https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/23721-drives-marked-read-only.html

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3587-change-owner-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-10-a.html

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3548-enable-disable-disk-write-protection-windows.html

https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/25076-normal-if-i-cant-create-new-folder-windows-10-a.html

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7859d8c0-7438-4836-8408-a0c550c8ba0a/second-hard-drive-says-writeprotected?forum=winserverfiles

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container

This is my first experience with Windows 10...